# NSSavePanel not working?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssavepanel

I can't get it to show any alert if I try to use a not allowed extension. When I say "not allowed" I mean I wrote

```
setAllowsOtherFileTypes:FALSE
```

but it doesn't work. If I set the allowed file types to an array of `@"jpg"` and `@"png"` (for example), and then I try to save "`file.tif`", I get no alert and the resulting filename is "`file.tif.jpg`"
What's happening? I'm on MacOS 10.6.8, Xcode 3.2.6

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSSavePanel* savepanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
 // set the save panel to only do jpg and png file
    [savepanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray initWithObjects:@"jpg", @"png",nil]];
    [savepanel setAllowsOtherFileTypes:YES];
 // run the panel
if ([savepanel runModal] != NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
  return NO;
```

Comment: dialog only appears if the alternative extension the
user enters is one that is recognized (by the OS, I think, but I
suppose it could be something specific in Cocoa).

Comment: take a look at this http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/185690-nssavepanel-and-allowing-unknown-extensions.html